# Не отображается текстура объекта после пары секунд

Tags: android, libgdx

Добрый день, быдлокодя на LibGDX столкнулся с вот такой проблемой:
При запуске игры всё нормально (слева вверху координаты персонажа)
[image]
Спустя 3-4 секунды или при сворачивании/разворачивании игры вот такая картина:
(Будто персонаж пропал, т.к. координаты 0,0)
[image]
Персонаж анимирован покадрово через свой класс `Animation` где изображение порезано на `TextureRegion`;

В чём может быть проблема? (Используется последняя версия LibGDX, джойстик производит только смену координат текстуры)

Код анимации:

```
public class Animation {
Array<TextureRegion> frames;
float maxFrameTime;
float currentFrameTime;
int frameCount;
int frame;
Boolean playedOnce;

public void dispose(){
    frames=null;
}

public Animation(TextureRegion region, int frameCount, float cycleTime){
    playedOnce=false;
    frames = new Array<TextureRegion>();
    TextureRegion temp;
    int frameWidth = region.getRegionWidth() / frameCount;
    for(int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++){
        temp = new TextureRegion(region, i * frameWidth, 0, frameWidth, region.getRegionHeight());
        frames.add(temp);
    }
    this.frameCount = frameCount;
    this.maxFrameTime = cycleTime / frameCount;
    frame = 0;
}

public void update(float dt){
    currentFrameTime += dt;
    if(currentFrameTime > maxFrameTime){
        frame++;
        currentFrameTime = 0;
        if(frame >= frameCount-1){
            playedOnce=true;
        }
        if(frame >= frameCount){
            frame = 0;
        }
    }
}

public Boolean isPlayedOnce(){
    return playedOnce;
}

public void flip(){
    for(TextureRegion region : frames)
        region.flip(true, false);
}

public TextureRegion getFrame(){
    return frames.get(frame);
}
```

Код при обновлении экрана:

```
public void update(float dt){
    float deltaX=next.getX()-shadow.getX();
    float deltaY=next.getY()-shadow.getY();
    float angle=(float)Math.atan2(deltaY,deltaX);
    float newX=5f*(float)Math.cos(angle);
    float newY=5f*(float)Math.sin(angle);
    shadow.move(newX,newY);
    Vector2 delta=pad.getDelta();
    if(delta.len()>0){
    if(delta.x<0) next.flip(true);
    else next.flip(false);
    next.move(delta);
    }
    if(next.isTouched(shadow.getBody())){
        next.hit(shadow);
        shadow.move(400,400);
    }
    cam.position.set(cam.viewportWidth/2f,cam.viewportHeight/2f,0);//next.getX(), next.getY(), 0);
    cam.update();
    next.update(dt);
    pad.setCenter(cam.position.x-cam.viewportWidth/2f+pad.getPad().getWidth(), cam.position.y-cam.viewportHeight/2f+pad.getPad().getHeight());
    render(main.spriteBatch);
}

@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch sb){
    sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    sb.begin();
    for(Piece p:pieces){
        sb.draw(p.getTexture(), p.getX()*step, p.getY()*step, step, step);
    }
    sb.draw(shadow.getTexture(), shadow.getX()-shadow.getTexture().getRegionWidth()/2, shadow.getY());
    sb.draw(next.getTexture(), next.getX()-next.getTexture().getRegionWidth()/2, next.getY());
    sb.setColor(1,1,1,0.5f);
    sb.draw(pad.getPad(), pad.getCenter().x-64, pad.getCenter().y-64, 128, 128);
    sb.draw(pad.getPadTo(), pad.getPos().x-pad.getPadTo().getWidth(), pad.getPos().y-pad.getPadTo().getWidth(), 32, 32);
    sb.setColor(1,1,1,1f);
    String s=(int)next.getX()+" "+(int)next.getMotion().x;
    glyph.setText(fnt, s);
    fnt.draw(sb, s, cam.position.x-cam.viewportWidth/2f, cam.position.y+cam.viewportHeight/2f);
    sb.end();
    shr.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    shr.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
    shr.setColor(1, 1, 0, 1);
    shr.rect(next.getBody().x, next.getBody().y, next.getBody().width, next.getBody().height);
    shr.setColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    shr.rect(shadow.getBody().x, shadow.getBody().y, shadow.getBody().width, shadow.getBody().height);
    shr.end();
}
```

Comment: Справа сверху?  Это если смотреть от лица персонажа?

Comment: @V.March очепятка, бывает, по теме есть что предложить?

Comment: Может он на координатах 0 0?

Comment: @V.March нет, при попытке вывести координаты в логи через ```Gdx.app.log()``` выдает ```NaN```

Comment: Код анимации и определения/ задания координат был бы очень уместен.

Comment: То есть, при обновлении экрана или анимации он должен был пересоздаться(например в процессе анимации)?

Comment: @V.March обновил вопрос, код там.

Comment: this.frameCount = frameCount; this.maxFrameTime = cycleTime / frameCount;  // в конце кода так и задумано?

Comment: @V.March да, т.к. циклическая анимация и при создании вводится время на один круг кадров

Comment: @V.March совсем забыл, если отключить обновление кадров анимации, то всё работает (двигается как надо и т.д.)

Comment: В этом куске: if(frame >= frameCount-1){ playedOnce=true; } if(frame >= frameCount){ frame = 0; }//  оба 'if'  сработают если fram ==frameCount.

Comment: @V.March и это не влияет на работу